# Sorting a file with Cygwin in Windows

Tags: windows, sorting, scripting, cygwin, rating

I have a file with thousands of beer reviews that I need to sort. Each beer review looks like this:

```
beer/name: John Harvards Simcoe IPA
beer/beerID: 63836
beer/brewerID: 8481
beer/ABV: 5.4
beer/style: India Pale Ale (ITA)
review/appearance: 4/5
review/aroma: 6/10
review/palate: 3/5
review/taste: 6/10
review/overall: 13/20
review/time: 11575857200
```

I need to sort top 10 beers with the highest number of reviews. The beer identifier 'beer/name'.

Comment: Sounds like a homework =)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a homework, but anyway (I like the beer), this is an [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) **starter** :

```
awk -F'[ /]' -v note=20 '
    /^beer\/name:/{$1=$2="";beer=$0}
    /^review/ && !/review\/time/{arr[beer]+=$3/$4; count++}
    END{for (a in arr) print a, arr[a]*note/count "/" note}
' beers.txt
```

It's easy from this to pipe the output to the `sort` & `head` command to sort a specific column & display N lines from the top respectively. (Or use `awk` itself, but it's harder...)